# Best Practices in integrating cryptocurrency as payment to my website

Tags: wallet, website-integration

I  want to accept crypto as payment to my website
(some common coins, btc, bch, link, doge, etc.)
and give authorization accordingly.

I was wondering what is the best practice to do so?

Should I create a wallet for each user?
or should I have one wallet and assign a public address to each user?

Also, I am using node.js,
Which packages are out there that can do these tasks?

Answer (score 1):

For Bitcoin there is [`BTCpayserver`](https://btcpayserver.org/), it's an open source well maintained invoice and accounting tool that accepts BTC and LN payments.

For other cryptos you'd probably not want to implement each individually, but go with a full suite solution provided by a for-profit company. As this is an open source place and a Bitcoin place, you probably won't find suggestions here.